# Overloading of operators

Tags: haskell, operator-overloading

I want to define an operator (call it `+-+`) that works in this:

```
if a,b are Char    => a +-+ b = [a][b]
if a,b are Integer => a +-+ b = a+b
```

I tried with:

```
class Summable a where
    (+-+)       :: a -> a -> b

instance Summable Integer where
    a +-+ b     = a + b

instance Summable Char where
    a +-+ b     = [a] ++ [b]
```

but I get the errors:

```
Couldn't match type `b' with `Integer'....
Couldn't match type `b' with `[Char]' ....
```

Is it possible to do this? How?

Comment: Note that `[a] ++ [b]` is just `[a,b]`...

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The problem is the type variable `b` can't be determined from the instance, even though it is fixed. (Having a free variable like that requires the function returns something that has any type, i.e. `undefined`.)

Can you give `+-+` the type `a -> a -> a`? If so, do that. (But it looks like this isn't possible.)

Otherwise, you could use [functional dependencies](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Functional_dependencies), so that the instance specifies the result type, or [type families](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/TF), so that one of the attributes of the instantiation is the result type.

For functional dependencies, the code might look like:

```
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses, FunctionalDependencies #-}

class Summable a result | a -> result where
  (+-+) :: a -> a -> result

instance Summable Char String where
  a +-+ b = [a] ++ [b]

instance Summable Integer Integer where
  a +-+ b = a + b
```

For type families, it would be like:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}

class Summable a where
  type Result a
  (+-+) :: a -> a -> Result a

instance Summable Char where
  type Result Char = String
  a +-+ b = [a] ++ [b]

instance Summable Integer where
  type Result Integer = Integer
  a +-+ b = a + b
```

(Thank you to Vitus and Vladimir Matveev for fixing the various errors I had made! :) )